Нагрузка анимации на процессор и GPU
Есть альтернативный вариант реализации этой анимации. Данный вариант грузит процессор и GPU. Или мне лучше сделать картинку с этим эффектом с анимацией движения по кругу?
UPD: картинка никак не повлияла. Основная нагрузка идет с анимации движения.


.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    margin-left: -180px;
    margin-top: -180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(
        from 0deg, 
        rgba(255, 192, 203, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 192, 203, 1) 100%
    ),
    radial-gradient(
        circle,
        rgba(255, 192, 203, 0) 60%,
        rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.5) 80%,
        rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.1) 100%
    );
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(10px);
    will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
<div class="spinner"></div>



Работа анимации на деле:


Я бы сделал картинкой и не выпендривался

А если блюр убрать и сделать размытие через градиент?

Отключение размытия особо ни на что не влияет

Реализовал это при помощи картинки и анимации кружения. Нагрузка на GPU хоть и упала до 5%. Но в какой-то момент без причин поднимается до 30%.

Уберите will-change: transform. filter: blur в целом ресурсозатратная вещь, а тут ещё и под анимаций, лучше реализовать размытие похожее через градиент, если не получается, то используйте изображение. И тем не менее, вряд ли проблема именно с этой анимацией.

Не поможет. Нагружает именно движение объекта. Я сделал альтернативный вариант, где все эффекты заменил на картинку. По нагрузке практически ничего  не поменялось.
